# MySQL, table requires to run "optimize" command too often

Tags: mysql

I have a table that is growing about *200MB/hour*.

If I run the `optimize` command on it, the size is reduced to *2MB* and start growing again.

The table is a WordPress installation with very few visits (~100/day).

I was wondering if there is something wrong with this table, this is the table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `wpii_options` (
  `option_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `option_name` varchar(191) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `option_value` longtext NOT NULL,
  `autoload` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'yes',
  PRIMARY KEY (`option_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `option_name` (`option_name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=16525 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

MySQL version `5.5.49-cll-lve`

Answer (score 0):

If unnecessary, try to reduce to:

```
bigint(20) -> int(20)
longtext -> text
```